# sql full text search keyword from table's column

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, contains, containstable

I have the following query

```
INSERT INTO FirstNames select FirstName from temp_names where not exists 
(select FirstName from FirstNames where CONTAINS(FirstName, temp_names.FirstName))
```

but I'm getting the error : Incorrect syntax near 'temp_names'.

because it can't see the table temp_names for some reason.

I tried using the query without the contains like the following:

```
INSERT INTO FirstNames select FirstName from temp_names where not exists 
(select FirstName from FirstNames where FirstName = temp_names.FirstName)
```

and it works, but it becomes really heavy when I reach 2 millions records and above.

how can I use full text search and pass it the column name, like the first query above ?

Thank you.

**Edit**

it doesn't matter finding the exact match or not

Comment: Do you want to find the exact match or you want to do a `FULL TEXT SEARCH`

Comment: @VR46 I want to find the exact match

Comment: Mysql <> Sql server. Which one you are using

Comment: @VR46 I'm sorry for the conflict, I'm using SQL server not mysql

Comment: You cannot use contains like that and If you want to find exact match then Contains will not do that. Your second query looks fine to me

Comment: @VR46, if I want to use it without finding the exact match, does it work if I can pass a column value or not ?

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
INSERT INTO FirstName(FirstName)
    select tn.FirstName
    from temp_names tn
    where not exists (select 1
                      from FirstNames fn
                      where fn.FirstName = tn.FirstName
                     );
```

You want an index on `FirstName(FirstName)`:

```
create unique index unq_firstname_firstname on FirstName(FirstName);
```

This should speed the query, assuming that `FirstName.FirstName` and `temp_names.FirstName` have the same data type and collation.

Note:  If there is the possibility that `temp_names` could have duplicates, then you really want:

```
INSERT INTO FirstName(FirstName)
    select distinct tn.FirstName
    from temp_names tn
    where not exists (select 1
                      from FirstNames fn
                      where fn.FirstName = tn.FirstName
                     );
```

Comment: both tables' columns have the the same datatype and both tables have the same collation.
temp_names has duplicates rows, should I create an index and use the second query you provided or use the second query without indexing the column ?

Comment: You want the index for solving this problem efficiently

Comment: I got it, thank you a lot, I will test it out today, and will get back to you.